# Symbol __mcount is not exported from dependent module /usr/lib/libC.a[shr_64.o]

Tags: apache, shared-libraries, aix, libc, xlc

I have compiled my code on AIX 7.1 using xlc compiler. The compilation is successful and I have created a shared library, but when I try to load the library on Apache I am getting the following error.

> httpd: Syntax error on line 54 of $APACHE_HOME/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load $APACHE_HOME/modules/mod_application.so into server:
>
> 0509-130 Symbol resolution failed for $LIB_PATH/libkiran.so because:
>
> 0509-136   Symbol __mcount (number 119) is not exported from dependent module /usr/lib/libC.a[shr_64.o].
>
> 0509-022 Cannot load module $APACHE_HOME/modules/mod_application.so.
>
> 0509-026 System error: Cannot run a file that does not have a valid format.
>
> 0509-192 Examine .loader section symbols with the 'dump -Tv' command.

Comment: Where did this `mod_application` come from?

Comment: mod_application.so and libkiran.so are our shared libraries. libkiran.so is dynamically linked in mod_application.so. We are trying to load mod_application.so from apache.

Comment: Then, most likely, the problem lies in your home-made components.